# Using canvas to take a picture of an image element

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I wanted to take a picture of a photo I have on my webpage using a canvas to get a local url for it. Obviously, this is redundant because I already have the url for the photo, but it would be useful in other contexts (like videos). When I execute this code, a white box appears that is not the image I use for testing purpose. Where am I going wrong here?

HTML:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script src="main.js" defer></script>
</head>
<style>
    img{
        height: 500px;
        width: 500px;
    }
</style>
<body>
    <img id="test" src="img_url">
    <button onclick="takePhoto()">Click Me</button>
</body>
</html>
```

JS:

```js
var width=200
var height=300
function takePhoto(){
    var test = document.getElementById("test")
    var canvas = document.createElement("canvas")
    document.body.appendChild(canvas)
    var cxt = canvas.getContext('2d');
    canvas.width = width;
    canvas.height = height;
    cxt.drawImage(test, width, height);
    var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    console.log(data)     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The 3 params version of `drawImage()` is

```
drawImage(source, x, y);
```

You did set the `x` and `y` params to the width and height of the canvas, which means the browser will draw the image from the bottom right corner of the canvas, which obviously doesn't do much.

You probably wanted the 5 params version

```
drawImage(source, x, y, resizeWidth, resizeHeight);
```

Where you'd set `x` and `y` to `0`.